# docker compose file is invalid, unsupported config option "container-name"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created a docker-compose file using version 3. but When I try to run it, it throws this error.

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.interaction: 'container-name'
Unsupported config option for services.user: 'container-name'
```

I have made sure my indenting is correct but still it throws this error. does anybody know what else I could check for?

Here's my compose file

```
version: '3'

services: 

  content:
    container-name: content
    restart: always
    build: ./Content
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    external_links:
      - mongo

  interaction:
    container-name: interaction
    restart: always
    build: ./Interaction
    ports:
      - '3002:3002'
    external_links:
      - mongo

  user:
    container-name: user
    restart: always
    build: ./User
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    external_links:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

I have been following Brad Traversey's tutorial for docker-compose and it matches up with that

Comment: In some parts you are writing 'container-name' instead of 'container_name'

Comment: Oh got it thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to be "container_name" instead of "container-name". that's where the problem was